# Como transformar document.write em coluna

Tags: javascript, html, matemática

Eu estou tentando fazer uma calculadora em HTML em Javascript. Eu já fiz a calculadora, mas estou com problemas em passar os resultados para texto em HTML. Eu tentei colocar em document.text, mas ele fica todo grudado. Desse jeito:

> 10 x 0 = 010 x 1 = 1010 x 2 = 2010 x 3 = 3010 x 4 = 4010 x 5 = 5010 x 6 = 6010 x 7 = 7010 x 8 = 8010 x 9 = 9010 x 10 = 100.

Quando coloco `\n`, ele ignora.

Alguém tem uma solução para deixar os resultados um embaixo do outro?

Este é o meu código atual:

```js
var multiplicador = prompt("Qual tabuada você quer?")
var limite = prompt("Até que número você quer que vá?")
var count = 0
document.write("<h3>Caso queira uma outra tabuada, aperte f5 no teclado. Caso esteja em notebook, segure a tecla Fn e depois aperte f5.</h3>")
while(count <= limite){
    var resultado = multiplicador * count; 
    document.write(multiplicador + " x " + count + " = " + resultado)
    console.log(multiplicador + " x " + count + " = " + resultado)
    count ++
}
```

Comment: `... + resultado + '<br>')`

Comment: Bom, já tem uma resposta. Depois dê uma pesquisada sobre document.write, atualmente são pouquíssimos os casos em que faz sentido usar isso.

Comment: Parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido/finalizado" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar um `<br>` em `document.write(...)` para quebrar a linha e exibir os resultados em linhas distintas.

Veja como fica:

```js
var multiplicador = prompt("Qual tabuada você quer?")
var limite = prompt("Até que número você quer que vá?")
var count = 0
document.write("<h3>Caso queira uma outra tabuada, aperte f5 no teclado. Caso esteja em notebook, segure a tecla Fn e depois aperte f5.</h3>")
while(count <= limite){
    var resultado = multiplicador * count; 
    document.write(multiplicador + " x " + count + " = " + resultado + "<br>") // adicionamos a quebra de linha no final com '<br>'
    count ++
}
```